# How to remove and/or modify the elements that are loaded into custom sign in pages in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've followed the steps at this link to setup a custom signin page for Azure AD B2C:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Which are essentially:

1. Create a custom HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Product Brand Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="api"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Upload it to a file hosting service
3. In `Azure AD B2C` > `User Flows` > `[ your_sign_in_flow ]`, set the following:

```
Use custom page content: YES  
  
Custom page URI:  [ paste the URL of your hosted file here ]
```

4. Click Save
5. Click `Run User Flow` to test the flow

That produces this login page:

[image]

Where the HTML of the `api` div is:

```html
<div id="api" data-name="Unified">
      <div class="heading">
        <h1 role="heading">Sign in</h1>
      </div>
        <div class="claims-provider-list-buttons social" aria-label="Sign in with your social account" role="form">
          <div class="intro">
            <h2 aria-level="1">Sign in with your social account</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="options">
              <div>
                  <button class="accountButton firstButton claims-provider-selection" id="AzureADPeople" role="link" autofocus="">Azure AD People</button>
              </div>
                      </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divider">
          <h2>OR</h2>
        </div>
      <form id="localAccountForm" action="JavaScript:void(0);" class="localAccount" aria-label="Sign in with your email address">
        <div class="intro">
          <h2 aria-level="1">
            Sign in with your email address
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="error pageLevel" aria-hidden="true" role="alert" style="display: none;">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
          <div class="entry-item">
            <label for="email">
              Email Address
            </label>
            <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="true" role="alert" style="display: none;">
              <p></p>
            </div>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="Email Address" title="Please enter a valid Email Address" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&amp;'+^_`{}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&amp;'+^_`{}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$" autofocus="" placeholder="Email Address" aria-label="Email Address">
          </div>
            <div class="entry-item">
              <div class="password-label">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <u><a id="forgotPassword" href="/<my-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signin1/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/forgotPassword?csrf_token=****==&amp;tx=StateProperties=****&amp;p=B2C_1_signin1">Forgot your password?</a></u>
                              </div>
              <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <p role="alert"></p>
              </div>
              <input type="password" id="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true">
                          </div>
          <div class="working"></div>


          <div class="buttons">
            <button id="next" type="submit" form="localAccountForm">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
```

In order to be able to customise this page, I need to know how to do the following:

1. Remove text elements if I don't want them displayed
2. Modify text elements if I want to change the text strings
3. Style text elements if I want them to have different font stylings
4. Wrap various elements in divs with particular classes to be able to apply a design
   (eg display the different sign in options as inline-blocks side by side etc)

My question is:

Is it permissible to do all of this via JavaScript (and CSS to hide/style text elements)?

Technically I think I could do it, but I'm not sure if it is allowed or best practice.

This page has a list of guidelines for using JavaScript in Azure AD B2C custom pages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow#guidelines-for-using-javascript

One of them is:

> Don't take a dependency on Azure AD B2C code or comments.

But I'm not sure how elements can be customised *without* being able to reference the code within the `api` div.

For reference, the `Page Layouts` page does have a `Version` setting, which makes me think that, if we keep the same version selected, the contents of the `api` div would be unlikely to change (and therefore not break any JavaScript referencing particular divs etc).

[image]

**Proof of Concept**

I was able to create this custom signin page:

[image]

With this custom HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Custom Login Page</title>

    <!-- links to CSS framework -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.19/dist/js/uikit.min.js" integrity="sha256-gHEvLzvpjU93VFTgu5myAgmc+0I1CzBzYe0YhTJ8uqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.19/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js" integrity="sha256-PxrcCuBlFkPVlPsGxNzt59W3EKYOH79z+v/tq9uFS2M=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.19/dist/css/uikit.min.css" integrity="sha256-f3SVFXP30MgahZ0Z7Lp1W02MuLgtiAtk8uFqTbGxNfY=" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- links to google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@200&family=Noto+Sans+Ethiopic:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS styles -->  
    <style>
    #api {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 25px 40px 40px 40px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .heading {
        text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 45px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .tagline {
        margin: -5px 0px 25px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #727272;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 12px !important;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .social {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    #forgotPassword {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }

    .uk-input:focus,
    .uk-select:focus,
    .uk-textarea:focus {
        border-color: #e5e5e5 !important;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- jQuery to get things looking the way I want -->
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("document is ready apparently"); 

    // hacky - put in a delay of 1 second to wait for the 'api' div content to be added
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Delayed for 1 second.");
        $(".heading h1").text("APP");
        $( "<span class='tagline'>Tagline Goes Here</span>").insertAfter( ".heading h1" );  
        $("#localAccountForm .intro h2").text("External Users"); 
        $(".social h2").text("Internal Users"); 
        $("label[for='email'], label[for='password']").remove(); 
        $("input").addClass("uk-input"); 
        $("#email").addClass("uk-margin-small-bottom"); 
        $("button").addClass("uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-small uk-margin-small-top"); 
        $("#AzureADPeople").text("Single Sign-On"); 
        $('.divider').remove();
        $('.social').insertAfter('#localAccountForm');
        $('.password-label').insertAfter('#password');
    }, "1000"); 

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- this is the only thing required for a custom page -->  
    <div id="api"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Don't take a dependency on Azure AD B2C code or comments.

This moreso is referring to our JS hooks and low level functionality, not the DOM.

You’ll need CSS/JS to manipulate the DOM for your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, is there anyway to 'know' when the `api` div has finishing loading its content?   So that we can apply our transformations after the `api` div has loaded all its content?  As a workaround, as shown in my original post, I am currently using a 1 second `setTimeOut` after `document.ready`, but that is hacky and doesn't look very good.

Comment: Usually document.ready() is sufficient.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { // transformations here })` does not work.  It only works if I add a `setTimeout` of 1 second within the document ready function.  Are there any events available from the Azure injections into the `api` div?  Eg when the process has started and when it has finished?  If so, we could hide the `api` div with CSS, wait for the Azure injections to finish, and then run our transformation code and show the `api` div.

Comment: @user1063287 Not sure if you're still looking for an answer but the `defer` keyword worked for me: `<script defer> ... do stuff here ... </script>`